# Removing the confidence band in ```qqPlot```

Tags: r

Consider the following approach for testing a set of observations coming from a hypothesized distributions. For simplicity let,

```
x<-rnorm(200)
qqPlot(x,  distribution="norm")
```

where I am using the `qqPlot` from `car` package. I get a Q-Q plot like this:-
[image]

Could it be possible for anyone to tell me how can I remove the band? As a follow-up question, could anyone provide me any reference what this band does?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use `ggplot2` since `ggplot` objects are way easier customizable. The data `x` has to be a column of a `data.frame` though.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(200))
```

Now you can add the Q-Q plot with `stat_qq()` and the line with `stat_qq_line()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(sample = x)) + 
  stat_qq() + 
  stat_qq_line()
```

[image]

If you're interested in the calculation of the confidence band, I'd recommend the source code of `ggqqplot()` from the [ggpubr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggpubr/index.html) package or `stat_qq_band()` from  the [qqplotr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qqplotr/) package.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `envelope=FALSE`.

```
x <- rnorm(200)
car::qqPlot(x, distribution="norm", envelope=FALSE)
```

[image]

> *"[T]he confidence envelope is based on the SEs of the order statistics of an independent random sample from the comparison
>   distribution (see Fox, 2016)"*  (`?car::qqPlot`)

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your quick response. Could you refer me to any document where I can get an explanation of how such a band is calculated?

Comment: @user642080 According to `?qqPlot` it should be findable in _Fox, J. (2016) Applied Regression Analysis and Generalized Linear Models, Third Edition. Sage._.